# Magnolia CMS: Cannot install module

Tags: magnolia

After the fall of the server with the site entrance to the admin page redirects to install the module "Magnolia Scheduler Module". When I try to install it get the error:

> Error while installing or updating scheduler module. Task 'Bootstrap' failed. (ItemExistsException: a node with uuid 54b56ea3-a89c-4736-b234-b62b63b6e602 already exists!)"

Maybe someone knows how it repaired?

Comment: May i learn, which version of Magnolia are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 5.3.4 version

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head right now, this may happen when one has scheduler module jar one than once? Also I assume that, you are trying to upgrade Magnolia, It is also important to know the versions of this upgrade.

One possibility to solve it to change `importUUIDBehavior` in `SchedulerModuleVersionHandler`. Therefore, one may change the conflict strategy as they wish and hence, not hit to those exceptions anymore. However, It is also important to be careful while doing these changes.

Meanwhile, you may want/need to use https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Groovy+module#Groovymodule-RescueApp for undetstanding what actually had happened.

Hope this helps,

Cheers